# Joda Time divide by other duration

Tags: jodatime

I use Joda time and I have to divide two durations, e.g. the first duration is **PT28620S** (7 hours and 57 minutes) and the second duration is **PT14220S**  (3 hours and 57 minutes)

```
7h 57min / 3h 57min !?
7h 57min / 3,95 = 2h 56min
```

Is there any possibility to do this. There is a dividedBy method at duration class but there a long parameter is required.
Thanks for all responses

Answer (score 0):

There is no method doing this but you can use the millis to get the result:

```
Duration d1 = Duration.standardSeconds(28620); 
Duration d2 = Duration.standardSeconds(14220);    

System.out.println(d1); // PT28620S
System.out.println(d2); // PT14220S

double result = d1.getMillis()/(double) d2.getMillis();
System.out.println(result); // 2.0126582278481013
```